# MySQL how to convert 00-00-000 to CURDATE in query

Tags: mysql

What I want is this.

Sometimes a date field in my databse is filled with 0000-00-00 which is perfectly fine. I have no problems putting my data into my table. So I am not looking for solutions aming the alternation of my tabel from 0000-00-00 to NULL.

I want to replace/convert 0000-00-00 to CURDATE or NOW, but I haven't found any solution yet.

The query I currently use looks like this:

```
$sql = "(SELECT
            date_format (dat_start, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dat_start,
            date_format (dat_eind, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dat_eind,
            o.nm,
    o.acroniem,
    o.orgid,
            r.naam,
    r.rolid,

                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM
                        relatie re2
                    WHERE 
                        re2.organ_orgid = relatie.organ_orgid
        AND
            re2.rolid_rol = relatie.rolid_rol
                    AND re2.dat_start 
                        BETWEEN dat_start AND dat_eind
                    AND re2.dat_eind 
                        BETWEEN dat_start AND dat_eind

                ) AS aantal

        FROM
            relatie

        LEFT JOIN
            organ o
                ON
                    o.orgid = relatie.organ_orgid
        LEFT JOIN
            rollen r
                ON
                    r.rolid = relatie.rolid_rol

        WHERE 
            relatie.pers_persid = '$persid2'


        ORDER BY dat_start DESC
        )
```

How can I do that? I hope my question is clear enough. I can find lots of info about getting the data into the table but almost nothing about the situation discribed above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to check if the field is `'0000-00-00'` or not.

```
DATE_FORMAT(IF(dat_start = '0000-00-00', NOW(), dat_start), '%d-%m-%Y') AS dat_start
```

Comment: Hi there Rocket, thanks you for your input. Going to try this!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an expression like this in place of `date_column` (which you should replace with the name of your column):

```
CASE
    WHEN date_column = '0000-00-00' THEN CURDATE
    ELSE date_column
END
```

For example, in a query:

```
SELECT
    field_a,
    field_b,
    CASE
        WHEN date_column = '0000-00-00' THEN CURDATE
        ELSE date_column
    END AS adjusted_date_column

FROM a_table

WHERE ...;
```

Comment: Hello Cdhowie, thank you for your reply. Going to test this tonight.